# Failed to find sync for id=0 in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, flutter-stripe

I am using flutter_stripe package and have changed android files according to their requirements.

- flutter sdk : 3.0.5
- flutter_stripe : 4.0.0
- device : MacBook Pro m1    pro

What showing in the console is

```
/SurfaceSyncer(12958): Failed to find sync for id=0
```

Sometime it is also showing

```
/SurfaceSyncer(12958): Failed to find sync for id=1
```

and

```
/SurfaceSyncer(12958): Failed to find sync for id=2
```

What does this mean? The payment is also not working. It shows the payment sheet. After we enter the card details, a web view of web hooks appears and then disappears. Then nothing is happening. Payment status leaved incomplete.Please help me

Project Level Build Gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level build Gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()


def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.stripe"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Best to report to the repository issues: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues

Comment: The message "Failed to find sync for id=0" is a generic error thrown by the app and doesn't provide meaningful insight on the issue. You can see reports with similar error logs, but causes of the issue differ from one another. It's best to provide the entire error log thrown when the issue occurred. Also, if you're trying to connect the Flutter app to a [local test server][1] to test Stripe, you can check the server's logs to see if it's able to receive requests from the app.


  [1]: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example/server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a harmless message that probably shouldn't even be in the Android logs. It is safe to ignore. I've added some details about this in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123255

Disclosure: I am a member of the Flutter team and have access to Google-internal bugs related to this topic.

Answer (score 2):

i manage to fix it by wiping data from the emulator
go to device mangager
on the emulator you are using, click the 3 dots and choose wipe data

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33654594)

Answer (score 1):

If the emulator is android:

- Open android studio.
- On the devices tab, select the one used and click on the 3 dots; click on 'wipe data'
  This helped me, right after I used the same code in two different projects, but with the same emulated device!